Hide a A Specific Tests for Multi-Cateegory TestFixtures
[TestFixture(Category="A")]
[TestFixture(Category="B")]
{
   [Test]
   void Test1() {}
   [Test]
   void Test2() {}
}

This will properly run each test twice, once for each category.... But I want Test2 to only run if Category is "B"....
Other posts show how to runtime Assert.Ignore().... but then the test still shows up with an outcome of other....I am looking for it to be "gone"....
This means the constructs must be in such a form that "Test Discovery" can recognize that the test is not included, and can not be an approach based on Test Execution/Runtime...
UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS:
When [TestFixture] is used multiple times with different categories the tests show up in the list of available tests in the runner multiple times... for example the above will show a total of 4 tests.
My goal is to ONLY show 3 tests...
Test1 with Category A
Test2 with Category A
Test1 with Category B
and NOT
Test2 with Category B...
Then when the tests execute, and I get the counts, I expect "3 out of 3 passed"

I started to answer this but then realized we're missing some critical info. The NUnit framework decides which tests to run, based on what it's told to do. The runner you are using tells it what to do and then displays the results to you. There are about five ways to run NUnit tests - excluding third party runners - so please tell us how you are running this one. :-)

@Charlie - it do0ws not seem to matter (dotnet test, visual studio, vstest pipeline)....
LEt me add some explaination to the post see if that clears it yup [better than hiding it here in this response...pleae give me a few minutes.

If the tests are not to be treated the same, then  the categorization has to be done at the individual test level.
public class MyFixture
{
   [Test, Category("A"), Category("B")]
   void Test1() {}
   [Test, Category("A")]
   void Test2() {}
}

Alternatively, if all tests in the fixture (including all tests you add in future) will be in category "A", then you can leave that category on the fixture.
[Category("A")]
public class MyFixture
{
   [Test, Category("B")]
   void Test1() {}
   [Test, Category("A")]
   void Test2() {}
}

Note that even if a test is in two categories, it is run only once. Some runners, e.g. visual studio when grouping by category, may list the test twice even though it is only run once. As stated in my comment, runners are responsible for how things are presented to you but generally not for how nunit actually runs the test.
